# SMF Forum shows 404 on all pages

Tags: forum, smf

I am a newbie to smf forums. I just transferred all my smf forum files and database to my new host. After setting all my path to urls and directories through my repair_settings.php , I am getting my home page without any errors, but all other pages except this page shows a 404 error.
 I really don't understand the problem. Could any please suggest me to get out of this prroblem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so everything really worked for me, after I placed .htaccess into my folder and changed the RewriteBase.